# Text not vertically centered in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I've created a Label with the following code :

```
func setupValueLabel() {
    valueLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    valueLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Black", size: 50)
    valueLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    valueLabel.clipsToBounds = true
    valueLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    valueLabel.textColor = valuesColor
    valueLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
}
```

I don't really understand why but the label is not vertically centered : 
[image: Label not centered]

Do I have to do anything specific so it can be centered ?

Comment: This might be a bit silly, but can you check if you have an extra newline character `\n` in your label's text? The code looks fine by the way.

Comment: That's what I checked immediately but i don't !

Comment: Could you try to reduce the font size? It looks like, `lineHeight` is for 50, but the size of font is shrunk by `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=true`.

Comment: It did the trick ! But I feel like if i've not entered the correct value and the font size adjust the problem would re-appear

Comment: It appears each time the font size is too big for my frame. That did the trick but it won't work for me since the view can have multiple sizes

Comment: I understand. But at the moment, I have no solution.

Comment: Is it some kinda bug from the framework or this behavior is considered as normal ?

Comment: I found it. `valueLabel.baselineAdjustment = .AlignCenters` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, can you write it as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The problem is that font size is shrunk by `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`, but it does not adjust the `lineHeight` automatically. It remains to be for original font size that is `50`.

By default, the text is aligned to its baseline. you can adjust it with [`baselineAdjustment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/baselineAdjustment) property.

In your case, you should set it to `UIBaselineAdjustment.alignCenters`.

```
valueLabel.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```

Comment: This did not work for me. Is it possible baselineAdjustment  = .AlignCenters will not work for certain custom fonts?

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 23):

Thanks to @rintaro, it works finally.

One more thing for my case, it didn't work because I was setting `ByWordWrapping`. I had to set `lineBreakMode` as `ByClipping`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me too. But why does only `ByClipping` fix the problem and no other mode?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked for me even with `byTruncatingTail` (I've set it through attributed string as `NSParagraphStyle`, didn't check without it - it just worked).