# How to center text in navigation title view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to have my navigation bar with left and right button (SF Symbols) and title aligned so it looks better visually but text in title view seems to have either some spacing or top alignment there and it makes title look higher which is not what i want. How to make text centered there?

EDIT: Seems it happens when using custom fonts, when i tried system fonts and other custom fonts some of them are displayed correctly

EDIT2: After further investigation it turned out to be the font issue, the one i used is designed not centered, which can be seen even when choosing font from dropdown menu, its not centered in selection either

[image: My navigation bar]

Comment: how your are add this label?

Comment: Seems it is your case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26649909/text-not-vertically-centered-in-uilabel. Set property `baselineAdjustment` of your label to `.alignCenters`

Comment: just using navigationItem.title = "APP NAME", i set up custom font in storyboard

Comment: @Dmitriy Lupych i thought about that but how to set baseline adjustment for navigation bar or navigation title, i don't have custom label there ?

Comment: Set your custom label to navItem in this way: `UINavigationItem().titleView = UILabel()`

Comment: So there is no way to set it up without using custom label?

Comment: OK, seems its a font issue, sorry for wasting your time guys and big thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary answer specifically for question in the topic but it is answer for my issue.

It turned out that my problem was caused by custom font which has space below by design. So what i did in the end is to lower navigation title by using this line:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment(CGFloat(5), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
```